# Firebase not defined in Vue JS

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to import firebase into my Vue JS CLI project. I've installed firebase via npm, and have imported it at the top of my `main.js` file as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import firebase from 'firebase';
```

I'm then initialising firebase using my config:

```
let config = {
  ...
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

I have a `src/views/Register.vue` component, which has a method which signs the user up and stores their details in Firebase, however, every time the method runs, it tells me that firebase is undefined.

I've followed many guides online, and it continues to return as undefined??

My method:

```
register() {
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(
        function (user) {
          alert('Account created')
        },
        function (err) {
          alert('Error:' + err.message)
        }
      )
    }
```

The exact error is: `ReferenceError: firebase is not defined`, could someone tell me what I'm missing?

For reference, my package.json file contains: `"firebase": "^6.4.0"`

Answer (score 0):

you have to import `firebase` on your component and also `firebase/auth` since you are using `auth()` :

On `src/views/Register.vue` :

```
<script>
   import firebase from "firebase/app";
   import "firebase/auth";
   export default {....
```

Comment: This means I'd need to load firebase into every single view and js file

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this](https://medium.com/@anas.mammeri/vue-2-firebase-how-to-build-a-vue-app-with-firebase-authentication-system-in-15-minutes-fdce6f289c3c) tutorial.

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue ?@RyanHolton